# SQL side by side query. Matching routes

Tags: sql, excel, db2

I'm trying to write a query or two that I can use to display two separate views of the same table side by side. I have records with orig, dest, and stuff. For each orig there is a record with every dest and the stuff related to it. So say one orig is Atlanta, and one is Phoenix. There will be two records that have both Atlanta and Phoenix in either the orig or dest:

```
ORIG    / DEST    / STUFF
Atlanta / Phoenix / Stuff for this record
Phoneix / Atlanta / Stuff for this record
```

What I need is a side by side listing of Atlanta with every dest on one side, and every dest with Atlanta on the other. I need to do this for every record. So the result would be something like:

```
Atlanta / Athens / Stuff  :  Athens / Atlanta / Stuff
Atlanta / Chicago / Stuff  :  Chicago / Atlanta / Stuff
Boulder / Athens / Stuff  :  Athens / Boulder / Stuff
```

It needs to end up in excel, so I can do two separate queries, but I can't figure out how to match them up. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
SELECT a.orig, a.dest, a.stuff from table a WHERE a.orig = 'ATL' and a.orig IN (SELECT b.dest from table b WHERE b.dest = 'ATL')
```

EDIT: Stuff is different between records ATL / DEN and DEN / ATL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.orig, a.dest, a.stuff, b.orig, b.dest, b.stuff 
from a inner join a as b on
a.orig = b.dest and b.orig = a.dest
where a.orig = 'ATL' 
Order by a.orig, a.dest
```

Since it appears you want have the dest Phoenix line up with the orig Phoenix, etc, and presumbably the stuff is different and meaningful

Comment: Yes stuff is different and meaningful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following answers your question of every combination with ATL in the middle:

```
select aleft.orig, aleft.dest, aleft.stuff, a.orig, a.dest, a.stuff
from table a join
     table aleft
     on a.orig = aleft.dest
where a.orig = 'ATL'
```

Comment: That is really close except it's listing like Boulder / Atlanta / Boulder, Chicago / Atlanta / Boulder, Denver / Atlanta / Boulder...

Comment: @DouglasBubbletrousers . . . And what is the problem with that?

Comment: Needed: Boulder / Atlanta / Boulder, Chicago / Atlanta / Chicago

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT a.orig, a.dest, a.stuff, b.orig, b.dest, b.stuff 
FROM table a 
, table b
WHERE a.orig = b.dest
AND b.orig = a.dest
ORDER BY a.orig, b.orig
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need every combination with ATL as dest or origin just do
SELECT a.orig, a.dest, a.stuff, b.orig, b.dest, b.stuff
FROM table a as a
CROSS JOIN table b as b
WHERE a.orig = 'ATL'
OR b.dest = 'ATL'

Your example has the a.orig constraint so also change that if you meant dest as stated in your question.